# Add NTFS Permission only to folders/files with inheritance disable

Tags: permissions, access-control-list, ntfs

Our file servers have been around for years, and as such, the permissions have gotten a bit crazy.

To start the clean-up effort, I would to make sure our "File Server Admins" group has Full Control to all files folders on our file servers.

I tried the below command, which does work, but for folders with inheritance enabled it gets the ACL twice (once inherited and once explicitly).

We are hoping to avoid having duplicate entries, so I'm wondering if there is a way using icacls (or another tool) to only apply the ACL the folders/files that have inheritance disabled - so those folders get the explicit permission, but any folders/files inheriting from them get only the inherited permission.

`icacls "E:\Group\Operations" /c /grant "File Server Admins":(OI)(CI)F /T`